# Validating two inputs with a same class name

Tags: jquery

I need to validate two text fields for null values, tried this piece of Jquery in my page,

```
    $('#div1').hide();

    $('#btn1').click(function(){

    $('.class1').each (function() {

        if($(this).val() == "") {

        $('#div1').show();
        }else {
        $('#div1').hide();
        }
    });
```

It is validating only the first text field. Any help?

Comment: What does `$('.class1').length` equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should follow below approach

```
$('#div1').hide();
    $('#btn1').click(function() {
        $('.class1').each(function() {
            $('#div1').hide();
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $('#div1').show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

As per your code validation is done for only last input I guess.

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sZT4f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code should show #div1 whenever any element in the selection has a `val()` of `""`. I'm not sure that's what you want, maybe do you want to show a different `<div>` for each of the input elements?

The [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function's callback will get two parameters, `index` - the index of the element in the array, and `element`, the element in the array. You could use this to differ between the elements you are validating:

```
$('.class1').each (function(index, element) {
    if($(this).val() == "") {
        $('#div' + index).show();
    }else {
        $('#div' + index).hide();
    }
});
```

See [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sseemayer/3TNr9/) for a demo.

**This is really unclean programming, though.** You might want to try the excellent [JQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) instead.

Comment: I need to show only one div and two text fields. initially my div will be in hide, on checking the value == "", i need to display. Thanks for sharing...